# Is it possible that "ProblemFact" be a shadow variable in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to optaplanner using 7.2.0. 
I have a question on chaining for vehicle route planning.

Does it mandate that the shadow variable need to have a annotation @planningentity even if its a problem fact?

Consider an example: 
I have techs and jobs to be assigned for tech. 
For me Tech (problem fact) needs to be assigned for job (planning) i am following VRP as its closely relates to it. I am following chaining (with both job and tech forms chain with tech being anchor).

I came across the documentation about shadow variable. 
My question is, can a "ProblemFact" POJO be defined as planning entity and still legal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shadow variable is a field or a property (=getter/setter). A problem fact is a class. A planning entity is also class (that is not a problem fact and visa versa).

So, I presume the question is: "*Can have I have shadow variable with a type that is a problem fact?*" The answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 1):

No.  ProblemFacts are classes that *do not* change in response to PlanningVariables changing, so can be reused between working solutions.

PlanningEntities are classes that *do* change in response to PlanningVariables changing, so need to have a separate clone for each working solution.

A ShadowVariable is a variable that changes in response to a PlanningVariable changing.  If a class contains a ShadowVariable, that means it changes in response to a PlanningVariable, so needs to be cloned for each working solution and is therefor a PlanningEntity.

If you put a ShadowVariable on a ProblemFact, I believe it will fail at runtime.